# MassTransit - how to handle MessageLockLostException scenario

Tags: masstransit

In the event where consumer is executing and the lock on the message is lost in the meantime due to duration expiring or intermittent connection loss - how can this scenario be potentially handled from within the consumer because currently if consumer finishes, the `MessageLockLostException` is thrown and another instance of consumer would have been started already.

To solve that - we wrote idempotent consumers, however, this is still an issue now where the first instance (the one that was executing prior to losing the lock) throws an exception because that causes the message to go the `{queueName}_error` by default and the MassTransit pipeline seems to ignore the fact that the message lock has been lost at that point and a new instance of consumer for the same message has been started.

So the summary of this predicament is that we can effectively get a message successfully acknowledged as well as it being in the error queue. I am looking if anyone has maybe successfully dealt with similar scenario or if there are some hooks in `MassTransit` where a consumer can work out whether it still has an active lock on the message it is processing.

Comment: Which MassTransit version?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson 7.1.8

Comment: You could increase the `MaxAutoRenewDuration` to a longer time period to prevent the lock from timing out.

Comment: We have done that so that leaves us with the potential gap where the connection to the bus is temporarily lost after the message lock has been renewed or does MassTransit keep internal timer of that and would try to reacquire lock.

Comment: MassTransit doesn't keep track of the lock, it relies on the transport client library to handle it.