# C# Masstransit with AzureServiceBus - MassTransit.MessageLockExpiredException

Tags: c#, azure, masstransit

I'm using masstransit with azure service bus; I'm trying to listen to messages in the service bus, but for some reason any message (even with 0 consumers setup), I get a MassTransit.MessageLockExpiredException; I already tried increasing the lockduration but error still persists; my configuration looks something like this:

```
serviceCollection.AddMassTransit(delegate (IBusRegistrationConfigurator<IIntegrationEventsBus> x)
{
    x.UsingAzureServiceBus(delegate (IBusRegistrationContext context, IServiceBusBusFactoryConfigurator cfg)
    {
        cfg.Host(fullyQualifiedNamespace);

        if (cfg is IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator sb)
        {
            sb.MaxDeliveryCount = 3;
            sb.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); 
            sb.MaxSizeInMegabytes = 5120;
            sb.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); 
            sb.AutoDeleteOnIdle = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        }

        cfg.PrefetchCount = 10 * 1000 * 2;
        cfg.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 10 * 1000;

        cfg.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Immediate(2));
    });
});

Exception:

MassTransit[0]
      T-FAULT sb://bus.windows.net/subscription c80c0000-bdcc-6045-d52d-08dc02f9e2d9
      MassTransit.MessageLockExpiredException: sb://bus.windows.net/subscription => The message lock expired: c80c0000bdcc6045d52d08dc02f9e2d9
         at MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.ServiceBusReceiveLockContext.ValidateLockStatus() in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/ServiceBusReceiveLockContext.cs:line 59
         at MassTransit.Transports.PendingReceiveLockContext.Execute(Func`2 action) in /_/src/MassTransit/Transports/PendingReceiveLockContext.cs:line 83
         at MassTransit.Transports.PendingReceiveLockContext.Execute(Func`2 action) in /_/src/MassTransit/Transports/PendingReceiveLockContext.cs:line 83
         at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock) in /_/src/MassTransit/Transports/ReceivePipeDispatcher.cs:line 117
         at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock) in /_/src/MassTransit/Transports/ReceivePipeDispatcher.cs:line 117
         at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock) in /_/src/MassTransit/Transports/ReceivePipeDispatcher.cs:line 117
         at MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Receiver.Dispatch(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ServiceBusReceiveContext context, MessageLockContext lockContext) in /_/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/Receiver.cs:line 186`

I already tried different configurations, adding and removing the lockDuration among other things, the debugging leads me to think that the problem is happening exactly at the configuration level, I'm not sure if I'm missing something for it to work.
```

Comment: Read last comment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68303497/masstransit-how-to-handle-messagelocklostexception-scenario

Comment: There isn't anything in that configuration that consumes messages.